# Matlab plotCamera function messed up yaw and roll

Tags: matlab

Help needed!

When I tried to visualize roll, pitch and yaw by using matlab drawCamera function, I found it mess up with my roll and yaw. The pitch is correct. I am trying to use multiple ways to correct it, but it's not working.

```
%  roll matrix
R1 = [-0.396609 0.917591 0.0269801;
-0.912533 -0.397282 0.0972107;
0.0999184 0.0139344 0.994898;];

% pitch matrix
R2 = [0.00132681 0.999776 0.0211259;
-0.863174 -0.00952158 0.504817;
0.504905 -0.0189051 0.862968;];

%  yaw matrix
R3 = [-0.0805096 0.877901 -0.472025;
-0.99671 -0.0664549 0.0464041;
0.00936982 0.474208 0.880363;];

h=plotCamera('Location',[ -3.37107 27.2489    333.757],'Orientation',R3,'Opacity',0,'Size',20,'AxesVisible',true);

set(gca,'Zdir','reverse')

title('3D Trace Visualization')
box on 
grid on
axis equal
xlabel('travel in x (mm)')
ylabel('travel in z (mm)')
zlabel('travel in y (mm)')
```

The pictures showing below is the plotting by using matrix R1 and R3. I need to make picture 1 looks like picture 2 and vice versa to make a correct 3D visualization.

**Need to perform roll but actually gives yaw**
[image]
**Need to perform yaw but actually gives roll**
[image]

The coordinate I follow is the same like the airplane shows
[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lui Hi, what I am trying to do is applying the matrix (R1, R2  and R3) to plot a 3d camera and get correct roll, pitch and yaw visualization.

Comment: How are you generating those orientation matrices?  Those are not standard cosine matrices for rotations.

Comment: @gariepy They are generated by optical tracker.